# Flutter: Building IOS release with codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, codemagic, apple-developer-account

I am trying to release an IOS file for only 1 device. I don't have a mac so I am using codemagic. I can get debug build for IOS but that file can not be installed on the device. When I try to get a release build, I get this error:

```
User arash13131313@gmail.com is not part of any teams on the Developer Portal. You must accept an 
invitation to a team for it to be available.
```

How can I be a part of a team in Apple developer portal? I don't want to release my app on app store yet. I just want the app to run on a single device (Only my boss has an Iphone!). So I don't want to pay 99$ for yearly subscription. The debug file is 100mb so I would prefer the release version. But if there is no way to get release build without paying 99$, then the debug release will become handy. But the debug build is not recognized by the phone.

Please help me, It's my boss's phone so it is really important :) . Thanks.

Comment: You cannot install debug file on other phones, if you want to install debug app, you install via xcode as described here https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/how-to-test-your-ios-application-on-a-real-device.html, however debug have very short expiry time so isn't useful for testing. So If you want to install app on real device and use (not just test for few days during development) You must pay for $99 subscription.

Comment: $99 is only to release it to the ios store.  If you just want to install it to your phone, you can use the free membership.